# Как отправить в качестве аргумента функции, которая принимает только тип unsigned char* значение типа size_t?

Tags: c++, c

У меня есть функция, которая принимает в качестве аргумента функции указатель на unsigned char, мне нужно передать в аргумент функции значение, которое содержится в переменной типа size_t. Как я могу решить проблему? Например, подобный код, который я хотел бы в итоге.

```
void func(unsigned char* var)
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    size_t number = 9;
    unsigned char* numberB = number;
    func(numberB)
}
```

Comment: Можно просто `func((unsigned char*)number)`, но вопрос — зачем? Почему это вообще может требоваться? Может, ошибка в проектировании? Словом, не выясняете ли вы, какой рукой держать микроскоп, вместо чтоб спросить, как лучше забить гвоздь?

Comment: нужно преобразовать число в строку. можно `sprintf` попробовать `unsigned char numberB [60]; sprintf(numberB,"%zu", number);`

Answer (score 0):

Бывают случаи когда надо сэкономить память и используется unsigned char
вместо жирного size_t, а функция может  принимать  unsigned char* не потому что это строка/массив а потому что мы его хотим менять.

```
#include <iostream>
void func(unsigned char* var)
{
    (*var)++; // из предположения что передаем по указателею так как хотим что то сделать
    return;
}

int main()
{
    size_t number = 9;
    unsigned char numberB = static_cast<char> (number);
    func(&numberB); // func(unsigned char* var) обычно бывает  func(unsigned char var)

    std::cout<<"size_t =" << sizeof(number)<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "unsigned char =" << sizeof(numberB) << std::endl;
}
```